# An Integers query

Tags: integer

I'm very confused. Can someone explain me this?

```
32     ⟵This gets to 32
00032  ⟵This gets to 26
```

<sup>See yourself at IDEOne: [Python](http://ideone.com/5MtyR), [Java](http://ideone.com/yN7TL) or [Bash](http://ideone.com/CApCO).</sup>

**Why do zeros on the left matter?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A prefix zero means the number is parsed as an octal. Octal 32 is 26 in decimal system.